How to make objects collide with edges?
Wrote functions for TShape, TRect and TMatrix objects.The TShape and TRect functions are similar so that you can call and create a collision for each object by changing the parameters.The goal is to make a collision like this (example on codepen and JavaScript) so that it counts when the borders of the squares intersect.
Example
Now Delphi.Now it’s like this: A collision is counted when the square goes completely to the top border or to the right, and also if the edge touches the bottom border.

Two functions localToLocal and hitTest are responsible for collisions.
pt := hit1.localToLocal(shape.x1-hit1.x1,shape.y1-hit1.y1,hit1);

             if hit1.hitTest(pt.x, pt.y,Form1) then
             begin
               hit1.lineWidth:=5;
             end
             else
               hit1.lineWidth:=1;

How can I change the "localToLocal" and "hitTest" parameters so that collisions occur when the lines of the squares intersect as in the "Codepen" example?
In the example I also use ModifyWorldTransform. This is necessary to set the object along the Coordinate Axis.
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, AppEvnts, StdCtrls;

type
  pRGB = ^TRGB;
  TRGB = record
    B, G, R: Byte;
  end;
  TMatrix=record a,b,c,d,tx,ty:Currency  ; end;
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    ApplicationEvents1: TApplicationEvents;
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
      var Handled: Boolean);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
  TMatrix2 = class
  private
     a,b,c,d,tx,ty:Integer;
  public
    constructor Create();
    function identity():TMatrix2;
    function appendTransform (x, y, scaleX, scaleY, rotation, skewX, skewY, regX, regY:Integer):TMatrix2;
    function append(a0, b0, c0, d0, tx0, ty0:Integer):TMatrix2;
    function transformPoint (x, y:Integer;pt1:TPoint):TPoint;
    function transformPoint2 (x, y:Integer;pt:TPoint):TPoint;
    function invert():TMatrix2;
  end;
   TRect = class
  private
      x0, y0, x1,y1: Integer;
      width, height: Integer;
      color : TColor;
      dragok : Boolean;
      Cs:TCanvas;
      matrix:TMatrix2;
  public
    constructor Create(_Cs:TCanvas;_x0, _y0,_x1,_y1, w1, h1: Integer; _Color:TColor; _dragok:Boolean);
    Procedure Draw();
    function hitTest(x, y:Integer;fr:TForm1):Boolean;
    function _testHit(x,y:Integer;fr:TForm1):Boolean;
    function localToLocal (x, y:Integer;target:TRect):TPoint;
    function localToGlobal(x, y:Integer):TPoint;
    function globalToLocal (x, y:Integer;pt1:TPoint):TPoint;
    function getConcatenatedMatrix(matrix:TMatrix2):TMatrix2;
    function getMatrix(matrix:TMatrix2):TMatrix2;
  end;
  TShape = class
  private
    x0,y0,x1,y1: Integer;
    width, height: Integer;
    color,color1: TColor;
    lineWidth:Integer;
    dragok : Boolean;
    Cs:TCanvas;
    matrix:TMatrix2;
  public
    constructor Create(_Cs:TCanvas;_x0, _y0,_x1,_y1,_lineWidth, w1, h1: Integer; _Color,_Color1:TColor; _dragok:Boolean);
    Procedure Draw();
    function hitTest(x, y:Integer;fr:TForm1):Boolean;
    function _testHit(x,y:Integer;fr:TForm1):Boolean;
    function getMatrix(matrix:TMatrix2):TMatrix2;
    function getConcatenatedMatrix(matrix:TMatrix2):TMatrix2;
    function localToLocal (x, y:Integer;target:TShape):TPoint;
    function localToGlobal(x, y:Integer):TPoint;
    function globalToLocal (x, y:Integer;pt1:TPoint):TPoint;
  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;

  shape :  TRect;
  hit1: TShape;
  a1:Integer = 1;
  b1:Integer = 0;
  c1:Integer = 0;
  d1:Integer = 1;
  HDC3,HDC2:THandle;
  StartX:Integer;
  StartY:Integer;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TMatrix2.Create();
begin
   inherited Create;

end;

function TMatrix2.identity():TMatrix2;
begin
   a:=1;
   d:=1;
   b:=0;
   c:=0;
   tx:=0;
   ty:=0;
   result:=Self;
end;

function TMatrix2.appendTransform (x, y, scaleX, scaleY, rotation, skewX, skewY, regX, regY:Integer):TMatrix2;
begin
  result:=append(1, 0, -0, 1, x, y);
end;

function TMatrix2.transformPoint (x, y:Integer;pt1:TPoint):TPoint;
begin
  pt1.X:=x*a+y*c+tx;
  pt1.Y:=x*b+y*d+ty;
  result:=pt1;
end;

function TMatrix2.transformPoint2 (x, y:Integer;pt:TPoint):TPoint;
begin
  pt.X:=x*a+y*c+tx;
  pt.Y:=x*b+y*d+ty;
  result:=pt;
end;

function TMatrix2.append(a0, b0, c0, d0, tx0, ty0:Integer):TMatrix2;
var a1, b1, c1,d1:Integer;

begin

 a1 := a;
 b1 := b;
 c1 := c;
 d1 := d;


 if (a0 <> 1) or (b0 <> 0) or (c0 <> 0) or (d0 <> 1) then
 begin
    a:=a1*a0+c1*a0;
    b:=b1*a0+d1*a0;
    c:=a1*c0+c1*d0;
    d:=b1*c0+d1*d0;
 end;
 tx := a1*tx0+c1*ty0+tx;
 ty := b1*tx0+d1*ty0+ty;
 result:=Self;
end;

function TMatrix2.invert():TMatrix2;
var a1,b1,c1,d1,tx1,n:Integer;
begin

 a1:=1;
 b1:=0;
 c1:=0;
 d1:=1;


 tx1:=tx;

 n:=a1*d1-b1*c1;

 a := d1 div n;
 b := -b1 div n;
 c := -c1 div n;
 d := a1 div n;

 tx := (c1*ty-d1*tx1) div n;
 ty := -(a1*ty-b1*tx1) div n;



 result:=Self;
end;

constructor TShape.Create(_Cs:TCanvas;_x0,_y0,_x1,_y1,_lineWidth,w1,h1: Integer; _Color, _Color1: TColor; _dragok:Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create;
  x0 := _x0;
  y0 := _y0;
  x1 := _x1;
  y1 := _y1;
  width := w1;
  height := h1;
  color := _Color;
  color1 := _Color1;
  dragok := _dragok;
  lineWidth := _lineWidth;
  matrix:=TMatrix2.Create;
  Cs := _Cs;
end;



function TShape.getMatrix(matrix:TMatrix2):TMatrix2;
var mtx:TMatrix2;
begin
  Self.matrix:=matrix;
  mtx:=matrix.identity();
  result:=mtx.appendTransform(x1,y1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0);
end;

function TShape.getConcatenatedMatrix(matrix:TMatrix2):TMatrix2;
var mtx:TMatrix2;
begin
   Self.matrix:=matrix;
   mtx:=getMatrix(matrix);
   result:=mtx;
end;
function TShape.localToGlobal(x, y:Integer):TPoint;
var pt1:TPoint;
begin
 result:=getConcatenatedMatrix(matrix).transformPoint(x,y,pt1);
end;

procedure TShape.Draw();
var M:TXFORM;tx1,ty1:Integer;
begin
   hDc2 := Cs.Handle;
   SetGraphicsMode(hDc2, GM_ADVANCED);


 //  SetWorldTransform(hDc, M);



  tx1 := a1*x1+c1*y1+0;
  ty1 := b1*x1+d1*y1+0;
   //fillChar(M, sizeOf(M), 0);
   SaveDC(hDc3);
   M.eM11 := a1;
   M.eM12 := b1;
   M.eM21 := c1;
   M.eM22 := d1;
   M.eDx := tx1;
   M.eDy := ty1;

  ModifyWorldTransform(hDc2, M, MWT_LEFTMULTIPLY);

  Form1.Canvas.Pen.Color:=color1;
  Form1.Canvas.Pen.Width := lineWidth;
  Form1.Canvas.Brush.Color:=color;

  Cs.Rectangle(0,0,width,height);
  RestoreDC(HDC2,1)
end;

function TShape.hitTest(x,y:Integer;fr:TForm1):Boolean;
var M:TXFORM;hit:Boolean;
begin
   M.eM11 := a1;
   M.eM12 := b1;
   M.eM21 := c1;
   M.eM22 := d1;
   M.eDx := -x;
   M.eDy := -y;

   //SetWorldTransform(Cs.Handle, M);

   Draw();
   hit := _testHit(x,y,fr);

   M.eM11 := a1;
   M.eM12 := b1;
   M.eM21 := c1;
   M.eM22 := d1;
   M.eDx := 0;
   M.eDy := 0;
  // SetWorldTransform(Cs.Handle, M);
   result:=hit;

end;

function TShape._testHit(x,y:Integer;fr:TForm1):Boolean;
begin

if (-x < 0) and (0 <= -x+width) and (-y < 0) and (0 <= -y+height) then begin
  result:=True;
end
else
   result:=False;


end;


function TShape.localToLocal (x, y:Integer;target:TShape):TPoint;
var pt:TPoint;
begin
      pt := localToGlobal(x, y);

     result := target.globalToLocal(pt.X,pt.Y,pt);

end;
function TShape.globalToLocal (x, y:Integer;pt1:TPoint):TPoint;
begin
  Form1.Caption:='function (TShape.globalToLocal) X: = '+IntToStr(Self.getConcatenatedMatrix(matrix).invert().transformPoint(x, y,pt1).X);
  result:=Self.getConcatenatedMatrix(matrix).invert().transformPoint(x, y,pt1);
end;


function TRect.hitTest(x,y:Integer;fr:TForm1):Boolean;
var M:TXFORM;hit:Boolean;
begin
   M.eM11 := a1;
   M.eM12 := b1;
   M.eM21 := c1;
   M.eM22 := d1;
   M.eDx := -x;
   M.eDy := -y;

   //SetWorldTransform(Cs.Handle, M);

   Draw();
   hit := _testHit(x,y,fr);

   M.eM11 := a1;
   M.eM12 := b1;
   M.eM21 := c1;
   M.eM22 := d1;
   M.eDx := 0;
   M.eDy := 0;
  // SetWorldTransform(Cs.Handle, M);
     result:=hit;

end;

function TRect._testHit(x,y:Integer;fr:TForm1):Boolean;
begin

if (-x < 0) and (0 <= -x+width) and (-y < 0) and (0 <= -y+height) then begin
  result:=True;
end
else
   result:=False;


end;

function TRect.localToLocal (x, y:Integer;target:TRect):TPoint;
var pt:TPoint;
begin
    pt := localToGlobal(x, y);
    result := target.globalToLocal(pt.X,pt.Y,pt);
end;

function TRect.globalToLocal (x, y:Integer;pt1:TPoint):TPoint;
begin
  result:=Self.getConcatenatedMatrix(matrix).invert().transformPoint(x, y,pt1);
end;

function TRect.localToGlobal(x, y:Integer):TPoint;
var pt1:TPoint;
begin
 result:=getConcatenatedMatrix(matrix).transformPoint(x,y,pt1);
end;

function TRect.getConcatenatedMatrix(matrix:TMatrix2):TMatrix2;
var mtx:TMatrix2;
begin
   Self.matrix:=matrix;
   mtx:=getMatrix(matrix);
   result:=mtx;
end;

function TRect.getMatrix(matrix:TMatrix2):TMatrix2;
var mtx:TMatrix2;
begin
  Self.matrix:=matrix;
  mtx:=matrix.identity();
  result:=mtx.appendTransform(x1,y1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0);
end;

constructor TRect.Create(_Cs:TCanvas;_x0,_y0,_x1,_y1,w1,h1: Integer; _Color: TColor; _dragok:Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create;
  x0 := _x0;
  y0 := _y0;
  x1 := _x1;
  y1 := _y1;
  width := w1;
  height := h1;
  color := _Color;
  dragok := _dragok;
  matrix:=TMatrix2.Create;
  Cs := _Cs;
end;

procedure TRect.Draw();
var M:TXFORM;tx1,ty1:Integer;
begin
  hDc3 := Cs.Handle;
  SetGraphicsMode(hDc3, GM_ADVANCED);

  tx1 := a1*x1+c1*y1+0;
  ty1 := b1*x1+d1*y1+0;
  SaveDC(HDC3);
  
   M.eM11 := a1;
   M.eM12 := b1;
   M.eM21 := c1;
   M.eM22 := d1;
   M.eDx := tx1;
   M.eDy := ty1;

   ModifyWorldTransform(hDc3, M, MWT_LEFTMULTIPLY);

   Form1.Canvas.Brush.Color:=color;
   Cs.Rectangle(0,0,width,height);
   RestoreDC(HDC3,1)
end;
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
   hit1:=TShape.Create(Form1.Canvas,0,0,150,150,2,100,100,clGreen,clBlue,false);
   hit1.Draw();

   shape := TRect.Create(Form1.Canvas,0,0,10,170,50,50,clBlue,false);
   shape.Draw();
end;

procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
var
   dx,dy:Integer;
   P : TPoint;
   pt:TPoint;
begin

   if Msg.message = WM_LBUTTONDOWN then
   begin
       P:=Form1.ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);

       if (shape.x1 < P.X) and
       (shape.x1+shape.width > P.X)
       and (shape.y1 < P.Y) and
       (shape.y1+shape.height > P.Y)
        then
        begin
          shape.dragok:=true;
          StartX:=P.X;
          StartY:=P.Y;
        end;
     
    end;
    if Msg.message = WM_LBUTTONUP then
    begin
      shape.dragok:=false;
    end;
    if Msg.message = WM_MOUSEMOVE then
    begin
        P:=Form1.ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);
        dx:=P.X-startX;
        dy:=P.Y-startY;

          if shape.dragok then
          begin
             shape.x1:=shape.x1+dx;
             shape.y1:=shape.y1+dy;

             pt := hit1.localToLocal(shape.x1-hit1.x1,shape.y1-hit1.y1,hit1);

             if hit1.hitTest(pt.x, pt.y,Form1) then
             begin
               hit1.lineWidth:=5;
             end
             else
               hit1.lineWidth:=1;
          end;
          startX:=P.X;
          startY:=P.Y;

    end;
end;



procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
Form1.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clWhite;
Form1.Canvas.FillRect(Form1.ClientRect);

hit1.Draw();
shape.Draw();
end;

end.


If both objects are controls at the same form (or other container), then you can apply IntersectRect() to their bound rects
